# Can I use Web Api 2 DTO's and WCF DTO's in both projects?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api2, dto

I have two projects using similar DTOs..

**Web Api 2 DTO**

```
public class SourceDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Acronym { get; set; }
}
```

**WCF DTO**

```
[DataContract]
public class SourceDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to create one DTO that I can use in both projects, or do I need for every DTO two classes?

Best regards

Comment: Did you try using `WCF` DTO in Web Api project?

Comment: hi michael. seems to work. thank you, that was easy :) even though it doesn't feel right :/ I think I should create a new project inside my solution called someting like "DTOs".

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create a common DTO project and then add the attributes for WCF with something like this - [Dynamic Attributes in C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2009/01/10/dynamic-attributes-in-c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WCF dto for both.